# What is the password in the image?

Tags: visual, steganography, computer-puzzle

For my first puzzle I made this, everything you need is in the image. The goal is to find the hidden password.
[image: The image]

You must look at the image to solve this puzzle, but here's a transcript of the letters on the image anyway.

```
The product of two
  prime numbers.

  T  S  N  Q  A
  O  E  O  U  S
  K  M  R  H  T
  B  X  W  S  N
  W  L  J  T  X
  M  C  B  G  R
  A  P  Y  Z  I
  J  R  A  V  V
  G  N  F  C  D
  Y  I  U  O  K
```

Hints:
1)

> You do **not** need to guess anything in this puzzle, not the *password* nor the *numbers*.

2. 

> The first sentence on the image is the first step towards the solution of the puzzle.

3. 

> This puzzle is **not** solved just by observing the image. In other words, if the image was printed on a piece of paper, this puzzle would be **unsolvable**.

4. 

> The entire puzzle is the image itself and it utilises **everything** an image has to offer.

5. 

> The answer is given by matching letters according to a specific pattern. It can not be guessed through random matching or guessing.

6. 

> Once the first step is complete, creating a *table* would help solve the final step.

7. **SPOILS THE FIRST STEP PARTLY**

> You have to download the image and inspect it in a different manner. There is no other way. No processing is required.

Comment: you can find many passwords in this, As this is the whole alphabet!!...

Comment: This puzzle is too broad. Please add more information so it does not become "guess my thinking" type of question

Comment: @North The puzzle is not based on guessing the answer or looking for it in letter combinations, the  steps are shown on the image itself. I will add a few hints to help out.

Comment: I think hint 1 is misleading. "You do not need to guess... nor the password". Isn't that whar we're trying to figure out? Or it meant we won't guess it but find it following a procedure?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I think the answer is:

> WINGS

Because:

> The picture is 181 by 271 pixels, which multiplies out to 49051. This is a five digit number, and there are 5 columns of letters, each with 10 rows. Using 0-indexing (the first row is 0, the next is 1 etc), taking the 4th element of the first column, the 9th of the second column, and so on, gives us the letters W, I, N, G, and S.

Comment: We have a winner! ;) Any comments for me to improve in the future?

Comment: @Lae I think it's a well thought out puzzle. If the original sentence had somehow hinted at dimensions or size instead of just "two prime numbers," it would have probably been easier to solve. Also, with hints, it's generally better to start out without any hints, and then add another one once every day or so instead of having so many so soon after the other.

Comment: @Lae You didn't need the hints or the textualized matrix; the [tag:steganography] tag is sufficient indication that the information is hidden in the image.  Also, the puzzle (or title) could have contained something related to the solution, otherwise it seems like an arbitrary word. Otherwise, this was a nice first puzzle!

Answer (score 2):

For

> the product of two prime numbers, there is the image itself, which the "product" or result of a set of pixels. The pixels are arranged in a rectangle of 181 px by 271 px, which are both prime numbers.

Edit:
Since

> the natural number 1 is neither prime nor composite, the product of two prime numbers is *composite*. So it is possible that the image itself is a composite, but Microsoft Paint might be insufficient for me to look into this further.

Comment: Someone is on the right track. Keep it up!

Comment: @Lae: Do I need sophisticated equipment for this?

Comment: No, as hint 7 suggests, *inspection* is enough, no processing is required.

Comment: Good. Hint 4 had me worried that this was going to require one of those magical NCIS-type-show algorithms that create order out of chaos by zooming in a pixel with no information and then suddenly out comes a secret.

Comment: I think overcomplicating things takes the fun away, I want my puzzles to be able to be solved by everyone! :)

Answer (score 1):

A first guess

> The dimensions of the image are 181 x 271 which are both prime. The product of these two numbers is 49051. If these are indices of the numbers, we get A S T O S. This doesn't seem right though.

Answer (score 0):

The answer might be

> Ten

Because it is the product of two prime numbers and can be found as follows:

> [image]

I suspect a number of other answers are possible given the vagueness of the question.

Comment: Good try but not that is not the answer, but you are on the right track in some way. This puzzle does not require any guessing at all, once you figure the first step out, it guides you to the solution.

Comment: @Lae Is there anything in the puzzle itself that can be used to prove my answer is not correct?  I think you may still need to constrain the problem a bit more to guarantee a unique answer.

Comment: Yes, for example if you take the "O" on the second line and the "N" above it and then the "E" diagonally you can assume the answer is "ONE" which is the product of two prime numbers once again, 1x1. I will update the hints once again to add a clarification on the actual answer.

Comment: Exactly, you have simply proven again that the answer is not unique :)  I will look forward to the updated hints!

Comment: @Lae Actually, that doesn't work, because 1 is not a prime number.

Comment: @Green I'm sorry, you seem to be right. I was unaware of that exception, but regardless, I think my point stands.